# Why doesn't TypeScript automatically check the type safety of the "this" variable?

Tags: typescript, type-safety

This example compiles with `npx tsc --strict a.ts` (TypeScript 3.4.5), but it doesn't detect the error:

```
class A {
    m () { console.log(this.f()) }
    f () { return 'a' }
}

const a = new A()
a.m() // prints 'a'

const sock = new WebSocket('ws://invalid-host.example')
sock.onerror = a.m
// when the socket has an error,
// Uncaught TypeError: this.f is not a function
```

If I run the output code in a browser console, the output is as described in comments above.

---

If I add `this: this` to the parameter list, it detects the error, as expected:

```
class A {
    m (this: this) { console.log(this.f()) }
    f () { return 'a' }
}

const a = new A()
a.m()

const sock = new WebSocket('ws://invalid-host.example')
sock.onerror = a.m // error TS2322: Type '(this: A) => void' is not assignable to type '(this: WebSocket, ev: Event) => any'
```

Is there a setting to make TypeScript check the type of "this" by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as expected

Not quite. The `this` type annotation is ensuring the *structure* of `this`. Not that it cannot be seperated (which is what you might be thinking).

```
class A {
    m (this: this) { console.log(this.f()) }
    f () { return 'a' }
}

const sockF = {f(){return 'another'}, m(){}, onerror(){}}
sockF.onerror = new A().m // no error!
```

> Is there a setting to make TypeScript check the type of "this" by default?

No.

> Why doesn't TypeScript automatically check the type safety of the “this” variable?

Simply because TypeScript comes from a natural and incremental world if making your JavaScript *just work* with TypeScript. This does sadly put *some* (still a lot less than raw JS) load of code on the developers.

Someone out there might want this JavaScript code to compile:

```
class A {
    m () { console.log(this.f()) }
    f () { return 'a' }
}

const x = new A().m;
x();
```

Things are allowed *simply because they haven't been explicitly disallowed*. A request to disallow would be welcome in my opinion for this case

Comment: This issue has been noticed before on 2014-07-15 ([microsoft/TypeScript#15](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15)), but that issue was closed after they added the `this` type. There are already similar issues for this posted in 2016 ([#10288](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10288) and [#7968](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968)), so I will not repost it there.